# Javascript/HTML slot machine game: will not run javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on this HTML/Javascript game of a slot machine. I know the math side of it works because I basically pulled it out of the python version I made and tried to format it into Javascript. The HTML stuff shows up but none of the actual program will function. I tried linking the Javascript internally and externally and neither will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Big Cat's Slot Machine!</title>
</head>


<body bgcolor= "#81D2F7">
    <h2>I'll give you 100 monies to begin the game.</h2>
    <h2>To win, you must get one of the following combinations:</h2>
    <h2>Three cheetahs will pay $50 * bet</h2>
    <h2>Three pumas will pay $30 * bet</h2>
    <h2>Three tigers will pay $20 * bet</h2>
    <h2>Three lions will pay $10 * bet</h2>
    <h2>Three leopards will pay $4 * bet</h2>
    <h2>Two leopards will pay $2 * bet</h2>
    <h2>One leopard will pay $1 * bet</h2>

    <h2>If you hit a balance of zero, the game will end.</h2>
    <h2>Good luck, matey.</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="myscripts.js"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript --

```
import random

var money = 0;
var cats = ['tiger', 'lion', 'cheetah', 'puma', 'leopard'];
while (money > 0) {
    document.write("You have ", money, " money");
    var wager= prompt("Press 0 to exit or any other number to bet that");
    if (wager == 0) {
        break;
    }
    else if (wager > 0) {
        var a = NumberChanger(Math.random(1,5);)
        var b = NumberChanger(Math.random(1,5);)
        var c = NumberChanger(Math.random(1,5);)
        document.write(a);
        document.write(b);
        document.write(c);
        if (a == 'cheetah' and b == 'cheetah' and c == 'cheetah') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*50));
        }
        else if (a == 'puma' and b == 'puma' and c == 'puma') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*30);
        }
        else if (a == 'tiger' and b == 'tiger' and c == 'tiger') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*20));
        }   
        else if (a== 'lion' and b== 'lion' and c== 'lion'){
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*10));
        }
        else if (a== 'leopard' and b== 'leopard' and c=='leopard) {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*4));
        }
        else if (a== 'leopard' and b== 'leopard') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*2));
        }
        else if (a== 'leopard' and c== 'leopard') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*2));
        }
        else if (b== 'leopard' and c== 'leopard') {
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*2));
        }
        else if (a== 'leopard' or b== 'leopard' or c== 'leopard'){
            return money= ((money-wager) + (wager*1));
        }
        else {
            return money= ((money-wager));
        }
    };
};
var NumberChanger = function(Number)
{
    if (Number == 1) {
        Number= ('tiger');
    }   
    else if (Number == 2) {
        Number= ('lion');
    }
    else if (Number == 3){
        Number= ('puma');
    }
    else if (Number == 4) {
        Number= ('leopard');
    }
    else if (Number == 5){
        Number= ('cheetah');
    }           
    return (Number);
};
```

I'm guessing it's probably something simple like missing a semi-colon or parenthesis or something, ya know?

Comment: How are you serving up ``myscripts.js``? Web Browsers expect to get their resources vai URI. ``src="myscripts.js`` is not a valid URI.

Comment: You have some missing quotes, look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JamesMills `myscripts.js` is a perfectly fine URL, it means the JS file is in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't really work like that; but anyway :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

After closing parenthesis of while and first else if you have put a semi-colon which I guess is wrong. 
And the condition (money > 0) will never be true as you are doing money=0; just before it, hence the control will never get inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Javascript does not import libraries with the import keyword. import is a Python keyword. So, you don't need the `import Random` line at the top of the Javascript file.

Secondly, your random number generator call should be like this:

`var a = NumberChanger(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);`

...and other mistakes....

The working file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/fCaSNVzz